# Convert individual json objects without delimiter to valid json file which can be processed at once

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a JSON Lines format text file in which each line contains a valid JSON object. However,these JSON objects are not separated by a delimiter, so the file on a whole is not a valid JSON file. 
I want to add a comma after each JSON object, so as to make the the whole file a valid JSON file, which can be processed at once using json.load(). 
I have written the following code to add a comma at the end of each line:

```
import json
import csv

testdata = open('resutdata.csv', 'wb')
csvwriter = csv.writer(testdata)

with open('data.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        csvwriter.writerow([json.loads(line), ','])
testdata.close()
```

However, the csv file obtained adds a each line with quotes and a comma with quotes at the end. How do I solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you need to convert `json lines` to `json file`, you can directly convert it into `json file` as follows:

```
import json

# Contains the output json file
resultfile = open('resultdata.json', 'wt')

data = []
with open('data.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))

resultfile.write(json.dumps(data))
resultfile.close()
```